Is there a way to get access to a googe drive file contents without using the Google picker?
We have built an AI bot which integrates with various systems - Google drive being one of them. We need to read the contents of drive files and vectorize it.
All the tutorials suggest we do 2 steps:

Integrate with Google drive and get drive.file scope.
Invoke the google drive picker to show all the drive files to the user so that user can choose the specific files which the AI bot can read.

However, the second step requires a restricted scope drive.readonly which we don't want to use.
Is there a way to get access to a file contents without using the Google picker?
In our case, the user is ready to share the url of the file with us. So we actually don't need picker. Can we access the contents of the file with the drive.file scope?
